# Apache access log full of unauthorized and suspicious requests, how to take action

Tags: apache-2.2, security, apache-2.4, spam

I have setup a small tiny VPS for my own website. Since it was live, I see many suspicious activity in the access.log file. When I was on a shared hosting I did not have access to this file and therefore unaware of it.

I want to know are these stuff dangerous, and if I need to take action, where do I begin? **here goes some samples:** Specially the first one, I do not understand what that user wanted to achieve!

> [Mon Feb 01 14:11:07.488860 2016] [core:error] [pid 30683] [client
>   169.229.3.91:46137] AH00135: Invalid method in request V\xd8}\x97\x97\xd1\x19\x01\xf4\xaf\x9ag\xa9'\x82h5\xb6\xc5\x84\x8a\x8b(\xd8\x97\xfeJ\xd6\xd6\x1e\xa3\x88\xb0\xfb.\xad\xcd{\xdf\x96"\xcfK\x8aU\x9b\xb8T\xf2
>
> [Mon Feb 01 08:40:14.268487 2016] [:error] [pid 1214] [client
>   95.213.177.124:24875] script '/var/www/html/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
>
> [Tue Feb 02 15:08:57.247512 2016] [:error] [pid 3346] [client
>   52.33.93.45:65203] script '/var/www/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise , aka automated scripts looking for vulnerabilities of unpatched servers.

You might want to setup a WAF like [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) and have it IP-block suspicious requests.

Patch your server regularly.

Answer (score 0):

A list of all errors present in the Apache webserver is available here: [Apache ListOfErrors](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ListOfErrors)

Your logfile entry with `AH00135: Invalid method in request %s` can be caused by telnet sessions (possible input error), proxy server (possible config error), intrusion attempts and others.

To deal automated with possible malicious Apache requests I highly recommend [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/).